# facing error >> cannot resolve method 'with(anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listner<org.json.JSONObject>)'

Tags: android-studio, android-glide

i am beginner and i am facing error when i want to load image using glide on this line.

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

whole code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageView;

    // ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
    private void loud(){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";
        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    String url=response.getString("url");
                    Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);



//                    Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("onErrorResponse: ","Error ");
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working for me...

If you haven't written INTERNET permission in your manifest then open the manifest file and add below code:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Now I have made only one change in your load method which is I have used try catch block while getting image url. The whole is like this -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    loud();

}

private void loud(){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";
    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            String url= null;
            try {
                url = response.getString("url");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(imageView);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("VERROR ","Error ");
        }
    });
               queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

}
```

}

Reply me if this solution isn't working for you.

Comment: thankyou soo much bro i am very happy i was very tense about this tiny error you solved my problem may GOD bless you.

Comment: Keep learning...Help others...Get help from others...Happy coding